# How to use disable option with country_select in a ruby on rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using a normal select field in a ruby on rails form, you can disable it as follows:

`f.select :place_type, %w(Club Range Other), {}, disabled: true`

But if you try this using the country_select gem i.e.

`f.country_select :country, priority_countries: ['AU','US','GB','CA','ZA'], {}, disabled: true`

it throws an exception with a message `syntax error, unexpected ','`.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: what does disabled: true do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
<%= f.country_select :country, { priority_countries: ['AU','US','GB','CA','ZA'] }, {}, {:disabled => true}%>
```

Comment: That did not work, I received the error message  ```syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...['AU','US','GB','CA','ZA'], {}, {:disabled => true});@output...```

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [country_select](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select) gem documentation, try that:

```
country_select(:country, { priority_countries: ['AU','US','GB','CA','ZA'] }, { disabled: 'disabled' })
```